Delete legacy asset

I have an issue with deleting a legacy asset in Google Earth Engine. Below, I have detailed the problem, steps taken to resolve it, and the errors encountered.
Frist of all, I can't find any icon to modify/delete the legacy asset, as you can see by the picture.
Then, I tried to delete this asset using the API request
(curl -X DELETE \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
"https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1/projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/USER/NDVI_from_Sentinel2"

I consistently receive a 403 PERMISSION_DENIED error with the following details:
Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The earthengine.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default.
Further investigation revealed that the asset seems to be associated with the project 764086051850. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this project, nor do I know its owner.
Steps Taken to Resolve:

Configured Quota Project:
I set my active project as the quota project

Enabled Earth Engine API:
I verified and enabled the Earth Engine API for my project.

Checked IAM Roles:
I assigned myself the roles/earthengine.admin and roles/owner roles in my project.

Attempted to Enable API for Project 764086051850:
I tried enabling the Earth Engine API for 764086051850 but received the following error:PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to enable service [earthengine.googleapis.com]

Checked IAM Policy for Project 764086051850:
I attempted to check the IAM policy of 764086051850 using:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy 764086051850


ERROR: The caller does not have permission.
Based on the errors, it seems I do not have any access to the project 764086051850. I also do not know who the owner of this project is, nor why my legacy asset is associated with it. This has left me unable to manage or delete the asset.
Every time I try to save a script, it is automatically saved under the legacy asset.
How can I remove this legacy asset?
